# Java ArrayList syntax error outside of main class

Tags: java, syntax-error

I'm trying to make a simple hangman game. The aspect I need help with is declaring the hangman stage, which is an arraylist. After moving this list outside of my main class, I received several syntax error warnings that were not reported before.

I could move it back to the main class but that would mean a bit too much code in one place for my liking. I'd also like to get to the bottom of this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

// omitted game setup code, ArrayList has been imported

}

public class hangMen{

    // here is where the error occurs
            // all of the lines below show a syntax error
            // All the lines have Syntax error on token ";" & ".", @ expected


    List<String> stage = new ArrayList<String>();
    stage.add("-------");
    stage.add("|     |");
    stage.add("|");
    stage.add("|");
    stage.add("|");
    stage.add("|");
    stage.add("|___________");}
```

// The last line has Syntax error, insert ")" to complete method declaration, insert identifier to complete MethodHeaderName, insert "SimpleName" to complete qualified name

I've never seen this come up before, and my teacher is confused too. Any help?

Comment: Your code needs to be inside a block. It can't be directly inside the class.

Comment: Your stage.add lines cannot be directly in a class. You need to add it to a metho

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs to be inside a block. It can't be directly inside the class.

Assuming this is initialization, you can put the `add`s inside an initializer block:

```
List<String> stage = new ArrayList<String>();

{  // Add
  stage.add("-------");
  stage.add("|     |");
  stage.add("|");
  stage.add("|");
  stage.add("|");
  stage.add("|");
  stage.add("|___________");
} // Add
```

but using initializer blocks is pretty unusual. Putting the initialization inside a constructor is equivalent to using an initializer, but it's a more usual place to do "complex" initialization:

```
List<String> stage = new ArrayList<String>();

hangMen() {
  stage.add("-------");
  stage.add("|     |");
  stage.add("|");
  stage.add("|");
  stage.add("|");
  stage.add("|");
  stage.add("|___________");
}
```

Alternatively, you can declare a method:

```
List<String> stage = buildStage();

List<String> buildStage() {
  List<String> stage = new ArrayList<>();
  stage.add("-------");
  stage.add("|     |");
  stage.add("|");
  stage.add("|");
  stage.add("|");
  stage.add("|");
  stage.add("|___________");
}
```

But I would just use `Arrays.asList` to declare the list inline:

```
List<String> stage = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
    "-------",
    "|     |",
    "|",
    "|",
    "|",
    "|",
    "|___________"));
```

Comment: This is both quite advanced. Maybe a constructor for the class would be better comprehended by OP

Answer (score 1):

## Constructor

[image: Image of cookie-cutter]

A class is a template defined at compile-time to be used at runtime for instantiating objects. Like a cookie-cutter is a template for stamping out a series of cookies.

Each time your app makes another object, another HangMen game in this case, you may need some set-up work to be done to get that object ready for work. This work is usually done in a [*constructor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)) method. The constructor is a special method that is named exactly the same as the class name. The constructor is also special in that it has no return value specified; all other methods must specify a return type or specify `void` while a constructor does neither. The Java platform guarantees that the constructor runs until completely done *before* the object will be put into service.

You can think of the constructor as that moment while cutting out a cookie where you get to decorate the cookie. Only after decoration is complete do you set the cookie on a platter to be eaten, like readying an object to be put to work.

Tip: I find it helpful to label my constructor methods with a comment line. Make it easier to scan when reading code.

This process of creating, preparing, putting-to-work, and eventually stopping a chunk of software at runtime is known as *lifecycle*, and is one of the key concepts to learn about in programming.

To keep your list of strings around for use after the initial construction, [define the variable as a member field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) on the class.

And, by the way, in modern Java you need not repeat the `< String >` on the `ArrayList`, as the compiler can figure that out.

Be sure to learn and follow Java naming conventions. A class name should start with an initial uppercase letter. So `HangMen`, not `hangMen`. In contrast, the variables holding a reference to an object (an instance) start with a lowercase letter.

```
public class HangMen{

    // ----|  Members  |------------------------
    private List< String > stage ;

    // ----|  Constructor  |------------------------
    public HangMen() {

        this.stage = new ArrayList<>() ;
        stage.add("-------");
        stage.add("|     |");
        stage.add("|");
        stage.add("|");
        stage.add("|");
        stage.add("|");
        stage.add("|___________");}

    }

    public void report() {
        System.out.println( "stage: " ) ;
        System.out.println( this.stage.toString() ) ;
    }

}
```

Let's try out this class in a `main` method.

```
HangMen hangMen = new HangMen() ;  // Invokes your constructor implicitly. At runtime, the class `HangMen` (note the uppercase `H`) is used to create a new instance (new object). A reference to the object is assigned to the variable named `hangMen` (note the lowercase `h`).
hangMen.report() ;                 // Invokes the `report` method for this instance (this object).
```

Notice the option use of `this.stage` versus `stage`. The `this.` makes clear you mean a member variable, not a local variable. The compiler can usually detect on its own when you are referring to a member variable versus a local variable. In prior years I preferred using the `this.` to make reading the code quite clear. But now [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)s with their colorization features provide a visual clue as to which variables are members versus local. So you may want to omit the `this.` prefix. I showed both here as an example.

Tip: For clarity, do not put a `main` method in your `HangMen` class. Put it in another class, named something like `App`, in its own `.java` file. A `main` method is basically a necessary evil, just a non-object-oriented hack to get our object-oriented heaven launched from the cold cruel world of hardware, operating-systems, and command-line consoles. Separating, and basically ignoring, the `main` method can help in learning Java.

```
public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        HangMen hangMen = new HangMen() ;  // Invokes your constructor implicitly. At runtime, the class `HangMen` (note the uppercase `H`) is used to create a new instance (new object). A reference to the object is assigned to the variable named `hangMen` (note the lowercase `h`).
        hangMen.report() ;                 // Invokes the `report` method for this instance (this object). 
    }
}
```